# Not getting check to submit after stopping submission

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check that an email field has a particular domain with the email so that only people from this company can sign into this store we are making for them. I am checking the value of the input and searching in the string for the value of the domain. that part works, i preventDefault action and do not submit form, but when the value is found, i want to submit but it still prevents it from submitting. It may be just after a long day of solving issues like this or something stupid in my code...please advise:

```
<script>
  $("#Email")
    .keyup(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var n = value.search("@atlanticbay.com");
      if (n <= 0) {
        $(".btn").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("prevented");
        });

      } else {
        $(".btn").submit(function() {
          console.log("we are good");

        })

        console.log(n);
      }
    })
    .keyup();

</script>
```

Comment: 1) You can't do this on keyup, you should do it on form submit. 2) Your `.click` and `.submit` aren't triggering clicks and submits, they are binding handlers. 3) Javascript validation can by bypassed, so you need to do this check server-side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for val() after submission.
2. Prevent default first, as you are prevent the browser from doing what it would do, with or without your client side validation
3. Use patterns instead of search, your validation will fail with inputs like "@atlanticbay.com@yahoo.com"
4. Since you are already in submit, you can push your values to the server using ajax, as you have prevented the default browser behavior.
5. At the end, your code will look like this

```js
$("#email").on('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var input = $(this).val();
 var match = input.match(/^\w+@atlanticbay.com$/i);
 if(typeof match != 'null'){
            console.log("we are good");
   // add submit codes here..probably ajax
  }
    console.log("prevented");
});
```